# Kivy - round edges of a toggle button

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm making a Kivy app and have 7 toggle buttons, but I don't like the design, so I want to round the edges to improve the look of the app, but I didn't find any solution on how to do it. I found this code:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    size_hint_x: 0.95
    spacing: dp(5)

    ToggleButton:
        id: toggle_button
        text: "Button"

<ToggleButton@Button>
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (48/255,84/255,150/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [58]
```

but then it doesn't change colors when triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by defining a custom class in your `kv`, and using it in your `BoxLayout`:

```
<-MyToggleButton@ToggleButton>:
    background_color: [1,0,0,1] if self.state == 'normal' else [0,1,0,1]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [58]
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
            
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    size_hint_x: 0.95
    spacing: dp(5)

    MyToggleButton:
        id: toggle_button
        text: "Button"
```

The `-` at the start of the rule for `MyToggleButton` means that the new class inherits everything from `ToggleButton` except its canvas instructions. You can see the default canvas instructions for the `ToggleButton` in the `style.kv` file that is part of the `kivy` installation. The above canvas instructions are just a modification of those default instructions.